# How can I get websocket connection to Kucoin Exchange

Tags: python, websocket, kucoin

How can I get websocket connection to Kucoin Exchange? I`m trying that code:

```
import os
import time, hashlib, requests, base64, hmac, json, websocket, uuid    
now = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
token = "my token"
SOCKET = f'wss://push1-v2.kucoin.net/endpoint?token={token}&connectId={now}'
params = {"type": "subscribe", "topic": "/market/ticker:BTC-USDT", "response": True}

def on_open(ws):
    print('Opened Connection')
    ws.send(json.dumps(params))

def on_close(ws):
    print('Closed Connection')

def on_ping(ws, message):
    pass

def on_pong(ws, message):
    pass

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, err):
  print("Got a an error: ", err)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open = on_open, on_close = on_close, on_message = on_message,on_error=on_error, on_ping=on_ping, on_pong=on_pong)
    ws.run_forever(ping_interval=10, ping_timeout=5)
```

But I get message: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
Maybe I use wrong endpoint? Which endpoint I have to use?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import time
import websocket,threading



def get_token(api_key,api_secret,api_passphrase):
    base_uri = 'https://api-futures.kucoin.com'

    def get_headers(method, endpoint):
        now = int(time.time() * 1000)
        str_to_sign = str(now) + method + endpoint
        signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode(), str_to_sign.encode(), hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
        passphrase = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode(), api_passphrase.encode(), hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
        return {'KC-API-KEY': api_key,
                'KC-API-KEY-VERSION': '2',
                'KC-API-PASSPHRASE': passphrase,
                'KC-API-SIGN': signature,
                'KC-API-TIMESTAMP': str(now)}


    req = requests.post(f"{base_uri}/api/v1/bullet-private",headers=get_headers("POST","/api/v1/bullet-private"))
    print(req.json())
    return(req.json())



def RunKucoinSocket(account):        
    def connect_websocket(account):
        now = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
        Data = get_token(account['apikey'],account['apisecret'],account['passphrase'])['data']
        server = Data['instanceServers'][0]
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(f"{server['endpoint']}?token={Data['token']}&connectId={now}",
                                    on_message = on_message,
                                    on_error = on_error,
                                    on_close = on_close,
                                    on_open = on_open,
                                    on_ping = on_ping,
                                    on_pong = on_pong
                                    )
        ws.run_forever(ping_interval=15,ping_timeout=10)

    def on_open(ws):
        print('Opened Connection')
        params = {"type": "subscribe", "topic": "/contractMarket/tradeOrders", "response": True, "privateChannel":True}
        ws.send(json.dumps(params))

    def on_close(ws,closemsg,closeerror):
        print('Closed Connection')

    def on_ping(ws, message):
        pass

    def on_pong(ws, message):
        pass

    def on_message(ws, message):
        print(message)

    def on_error(ws, err):
        print("Got a an error: ", err)


    connect_websocket(account)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {
        "username":"Nate",
        "exchange":"Kucoin",
        "apikey":'KEY',
        "apisecret":"SECRET",
        "passphrase":"password"
    }
    RunKucoinSocket(data)
    time.sleep(1000)
```

I hope this helps - Its formatted weird since I'm using it for scale but it should do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

just enough change this item (push1-v2.kucoin.net) to (ws-api.kucoin.com)